# Can not remove the old icon from an app - why?

Tags: android, icons, xiaomi

I just updated an Android app.

I changed icon and logo.

I removed from my mobile and installed. App icon is new one. Also logo is new one.

But when i click (my phone is Xiaomi mi 5 plus) show open apps button, i see my app with old icon!

https://cdn57.androidauthority.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/icon-pack-manual-edit.png

It is like this in the picture.

When i click edit on my application, and then click logo, i see "edit icon" screen. Bottom of 2 icons of old icon.

Bottom of it "built-in icon".
Bottom of it "local picture"

When i click builtin icon, i see icons from other apps and also see old icon! But cant see new icon!

But in the app menu, it is with new icon.

In `manifest`, i correctly put my image:

```
    android:icon="@drawable/xx"
    android:logo="@drawable/xx"
```

Pleease tell me how  can i delete that icon from my phone?

After i delete app from mobile, i look `builtin icons` from another application after clicking edit. There is no icon of old app of. So, new app is bringing it but how? I already deleted the `png jpg` files of that from `res`. Where does old icon come?

Comment: Did you try a Clean/Rebuild Build?

Comment: @grant on ide? Yes. Also invalidate caches, restarting.

Comment: I created another project and copied all res, manifests, java classes and now no problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to delete the app from your phone and download it again. I have experienced the same problems but this worked for me.

Comment: I already deleted 5 times. And i did not install also. It is just coming from ADB usb while running from ide. But i already deleted lots of times.

Comment: I think your activity.xml overrides it.